Necessary or sufficient conditions for the $k$-fold intersection to be empty in a covering with a "tree structure"
Consider a finite collection of $d$-dimensional balls $\mathfrak{B}=\{B_1,\ldots,B_n\}$ which cover a PL $d$-manifold $M$, i.e. $M=\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}B_i$. Suppose we want to compute the Euler characteristic $\chi$ or homology of $M$ from the covering. This will require some knowledge of the intersections of the $B_i$. What is known in terms of necessary and/or sufficient conditions (either on $\mathfrak{B}$ or on $M$) to ensure that for some $k$, the $k$-fold intersections of the $B_i$ are empty (or contractible, or in some other way "controllable", etc.)?
In my specific case $d=4$, $M$ is simply-connected, and $\mathfrak{B}$ has a "tree" structure to it - that is, if you were to draw a node for each $B_i$ and an arc between two nodes if and only if there was a gluing between the two corresponding balls, then the graph you would get would be a tree. Ideally I'd like to be able to say something about the intersections for $k\geq 3$ (e.g. that the intersections are empty).

If  there was a non-empty $k$-fold intersection, wouldn't the graph contain a $k-1$-simplex?
